# What species of spider is this? Could anyone help

Tags: species-identification, zoology, arachnology, arthropod

[image]

This image was taken in assam, India. The size was around 1cm. Could anyone help identify?

Comment: can you add an estimated size? 5 mm? 5 cm?

Answer (score 1):

This is a male *Carrhotus sannio* (the females are brown/grey). The white dorsal stripe on the cephalothorax is right beneath the outside eye; the upside-down v-marks on the back of the abdomen point to two white lines (sometimes broken) which run parallel to the length.

Gallery of males:
https://inaturalist.ca/taxa/334660-Carrhotus-sannio/browse_photos?quality_grade=any&term_id=9&term_value_id=11

Answer (score -1):

It looks like Adanson House Spider, Hasarius adansoni. From the eyes, it's definitely a salticid, and the reported 8mm size for females is close to the 1cm you estimated for yours. Here's an image from [spiderid.com](https://spiderid.com/spider/salticidae/hasarius/adansoni/) with similar markings:

[image]

Comment: Pattern of white strips and dots is different in both images. It is definitely Jumping Spider (salticid), but not Hasarius adansoni.